# Is this still considered an implementation of the strategy pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics

In my project I have different types of entities.
I get the data for these entities in text files from a 3rd party.
I've written a class to read and parse these text files, using the strategy pattern.
The method in this class must return different entity types so I've made the entire class generic - something like this:

```
public class Parser<T>
{
    public IStrategy<T> strategy { get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<T> LoadFromFile()
    { 
        // implementation details, not interesting
    }
}
```

But the problem is that now I need a new instance of Parser for every entity I load, so I changed my initial implementation into this:

```
public class Parser
{
    public IEnumerable<T> LoadFromFile(IStrategy<T> strategy)
    {
        // implementation details, not interesting
    }
}
```

So, is this still considered as an implementation of the strategy pattern?

If not, is there any way I could return `IEnumerable<T>` without having to specify what type `T` actually is anywhere but in the `IStrategy<T>`?

Comment: Why would it not? You should edit in your concerns so the answers can be tailored to what you actually want to know, otherwise, you're just going to receive a yes/no answer, which is not very interesting.

Comment: It's more a question out of curiosity then anything else. I like this solution and don't think I'll change that, I'm just wondering if it's still considered an implementation of the strategy design pattern.

Comment: If the strategy changes during the lifetime of the Parser object then it is more of a [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: "But the problem is that now I need a new instance of Parser for every entity I load" Why are you concerned about this?

Comment: @ABittersweetLife not unless it's the IStrategy object that sets the next state (strategy), which is obviously impossible in the second implementation. Also, do you have a source for the claim that a strategy must not be changed during the object's lifetime? I've never heard of that.

Comment: @ABittersweetLife I'm not so sure about that, since the `IStrategy` doesn't change anything in the `Parser` class. In fact, the `Parser` class does not have any state to be changed - it has no fields or properties.

Comment: On the other hand who cares what pattern this is? As long as you pass the dependency via DI and both classes are decoupled and there is the `IStrategy<T>` abstraction between them, I'd say you're doing fine.

Comment: @ErikEidt I thought that the entire point of the strategy pattern is that the "executer" never need to change, only the strategy. The way I see it, If I have to create a new instance of the `Parser` for every `T`, I loose the benefit of the strategy pattern.

Comment: @t3chb0t as I wrote in my first comment, it's more a question out of curiosity.

Comment: @doubleYou, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658192/what-is-the-difference-between-strategy-design-pattern-and-state-design-pattern) has some interesting discussion on the Statergy vs State pattern. I believe it is identified more based on the context.

Comment: I would suggest to you that the code is more interesting than the specific word that is attached to it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled but that doesn't mean you can only have one instance. You can still have multiple instances with different (or even the same) strategy. You just shouldn't have to modify the code of `Parser` to change the parsing strategy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I totally agree. as I wrote, just curious.

Comment: @ABittersweetLife thanks, but I couldn't really find anything there that supports your claim.

Comment: @doubleYou yes, I know. But the fact that I would need to specify what `T` is twice for each entity bugs me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I'm not saying you can't do it the way you propose. Just wanted to clarify that you still have the benefit of the strategy pattern even with multiple instances.

Comment: You wrote *"The method in this class must return different entity types "*, but currently both variants of this method return only entities of only one type `T`, which the caller has to pick beforehand. Is that really what you are after? From your description, I was expecting something where the file content itself should determine the entity types, and not the caller.

Comment: @DocBrown I don't know how can such a thing be done in c# unless the method will return `dynamic`. I don't want to use `dynamic` if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, you are still using Strategy pattern in less explicit way. However your code after change does not fully reflect that.
You'd have to present the IStrategy interface fot completeness.

However the main line of my thought is rather so: patterns are not blueprints, they are rather intellectual scaffold that more it is modified for concrete use the better it is understood and grasped.

Comment: Thanks. The `IStrategy` interface only exposes a few properties such as file name to parse etc', and a method for parsing a single instance of `T` from a row in the text file.